# Obtain file name of the view associated with an action in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails 3.2. I want to be able to obtain the file name of the view that will be rendered by the action being executed in the controller.  I want to get the last modified date of the file, but I am unsure how to dynamically get the file name of the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full path name of the current template in Rails 3:

**Within View environment:**

```
<%= @view_renderer.lookup_context.find_template(@virtual_path).identifier %>
```

**Within controller actions:**

```
# example

def index
  @template_path = lookup_context.find_template("#{controller_path}/#{action_name}").identifier
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do within the controller action and I'm not even sure it's possible since the controller action doesn't know which view will be rendered, if any, since a redirect is possible. But given you know the file extension of the view and assuming it's named the same as the action, you can do this:

```
Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "views", controller_name, action_name + ".html.erb").to_s
```

Within the view, you can do:

```
<%= __FILE__ %>
```